# Why do i have to power off and on my router every once in awhile?

Tags: router

It seems my router gets frozen once in awhile and i have to power it off and on. Why do i have to do this?

Comment: Because your router is crap, and you should buy a better one?

Comment: How old are you? You think you can build a better router than a Linksys WRT54G?

Comment: well, that depends entirely on the version you have, Cisco did a great job to screw up the WRT54G when they bought Linksys. :)

Comment: +1 molly.  my v.2 is awesome.  i wouldn't buy a recent version tho.

Comment: Switching firmware from manufacturer's to DD-WRT may solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having used the same model of router as you for a number of months, I have seen this problem occur several times due apparently to overheating.  Clearing out some clutter around it, moving it to a somewhat better ventilated space, and blowing out the vents with compressed air seemed to alleviate the problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say it could be a number of things.

If you mean it simply loses internet connection and restarting it allows you to reconnect, it could be a problem at your ISP / phone line, you simply need to look for a option such as auto reconnect / connect on line drop.

If however you mean it is totally dead and cannot ping, logon or do anything, it is a problem with the router and is because of one of the following:

- Router is old / wear and tear.
- Router has become damaged.
- Router has bad firmware.
- Router is simply poorly manufactured.

Comment: @~quack... I am good with tech knowledge, not so good at English! Thanks!... If you have grammar OCD, feel free to look through all my answer history! got enough to keep you occupied for a while!

Comment: you're not that bad.  the phrase "ware and tare" just set me a-twitchin' for some reason. :) those are perfectly normal words, they just don't mean the same thing.